# angular2 generate component from just a string

Tags: angular

Please, tell how to do the following in Angular2/4 :

Component `SomeComponent` gets from `@Input` the following html as a string :

```
  `<am-input
    [placeholder]="'Placeholder'"
    [disabled]="true">
  </am-input>`
```

How can `SomeComponent` create a component inside itself from only that string ?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I manually sanitize in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577347/how-do-i-manually-sanitize-in-angular2)

Comment: @Aravind the example you gave - they have strings with simple html, not html which must be handled by angular before. Or that does not matter for DomSanitize?

Answer (score 3):

The only option is to use JIT compiler and compile it when you get it. Read the [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e), specifically `Creating components on the fly` part. It explains the process in details. Here is the gist:

```
class SomeComponent {
  @Input inputTpl;
  constructor(private _compiler: Compiler,
            private _injector: Injector,
            private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) {
  }

  ngOnChanges() {  
    const tmpCmp = Component({template: inputTpl})(class {});
    const tmpModule = NgModule({declarations: [tmpCmp]})(class {});

    this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
      .then((factories) => {
        const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
        const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
        cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';
        this.vc.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
      })
    }
```

Comment: I got the following error : `ERROR Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'placeholder' since it isn't a known property of 'am-input'.` But I've imported `am-input module` in the `parent module`. Though if I pass to `Component()(class {})` instead of empty class - the `the exact component class` (which I'm trying to dynamically generate) and same with `NgModule(..)(AmInputModule)` - everything is ok. But There are very many components which can be passed by `@Input`. It sounds sad if I need to pass in @Input not only code, but also  component and module classes. How can I avoid that?

Comment: @AndreyPonomarenko, can you put your code in the question details or better yet create a plunker?