# Passing a component as a prop in angular

Tags: angular, components

Is it possible?

Something like:

```
<myComponent [component]="childComponenet" />
```

I want to generate `ngFor` inside the `myComponent`.

Comment: What do you want to loop ? Loop childComponenet multi time ?

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128024/angular2-generate-component-from-just-a-string