# Trying to create dynamic component with template in a string

Tags: angular

For my project, I'm trying to create dynamic component with a template in a string which contains multiple variable.
So I'm using this answer: [angular2 generate component from just a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128024/angular2-generate-component-from-just-a-string)

And it works well to display my data in my template.
But, I can't use directive like ngIf, ngModel etc...
I have the classic error: `"NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'span' (used in the 'DynamicComponent' component template)."`

I import well CommonModule and FormsModule of course.

```
                    const tmpCmp = Component({ template: myTemplate })(class { });
                    const tmpModule = NgModule({ declarations: [tmpCmp], imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule] })(class { });


                    const mod = this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(tmpModule);
                    const factory = mod.componentFactories.find((comp) =>
                        comp.componentType === tmpCmp
                    );
                    const cmpRef = factory.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
                    cmpRef.instance.name = `dynamic_${j}`;
                    cmpRef.instance.data = this.data[j];
                    this.listVc.get(j).insert(cmpRef.hostView);
```

I'm on Angular 14 by the way.

My template looks like:

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents text-center"> 
<input [value]="data.lastName">
<span *ngIf="data.teletrav" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: What does your DynamicComponent look like? Do you need to import CommonModule into the hostView aswell?

Comment: Please update your question.

Comment: Can you provide your issue with a stackblitz?

Comment: I made this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xwu1kg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,angular.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts
But on stackblitz, it's working well...

Comment: Cant you take the new code from stackblitz? There are even different things used between your question and stackblitz

Comment: Looks different because I use the new Angular 13/14 methods to create component/module. but the logical and result is the same

Comment: Okay so in my project it works well now when I diisabled AOT. But impossible when it is enabled. I tried some solutions with JIT (like this: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/compiling-angular-templates-runtime-dima-slivin) but still the same problem

Comment: I am wondering. What do you mean with "new Angular 13/14 methods to create component" ? Did you mean your question or stackblitz? Because "_compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync" is marked as deprecated.
https://angular.io/api/core/Compiler